# Docker doesn't see a binary in PATH inside container

Tags: bash, shell, docker, alpine-linux

I'm trying to build a Docker image to help automatize code generation from Google Protocol Buffers spec files.

My current Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:latest

WORKDIR /protobuf
VOLUME /dst

RUN apk update \
 && apk add --no-cache bash \
 && apk add --virtual .build-deps curl unzip \
 && curl -k -L https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/download/v3.6.0/protoc-3.6.0-linux-x86_64.zip -o protoc.zip \
 && unzip protoc.zip \
 && rm protoc.zip \
 && chmod +x ./bin/protoc \
 && apk --purge del .build-deps

COPY . spec/
RUN chmod +x spec/entrypoint.sh

ENV SRC_DIR=/usr/src/protoc/spec DST_DIR=/dst PATH=/protobuf/bin:${PATH}
ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/bash" ]
```

When I build and run it with TTY enabled, it runs without issue. However, shell inside the container is somehow unable to see the `/protobuf/bin/protoc` binary, even though it should be able to:

```
bash-4.4# echo $PATH
/protobuf/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
bash-4.4# ls -l /protobuf/bin
total 4444
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root       4548312 Jun 15 23:40 protoc
bash-4.4# protoc
bash: /protobuf/bin/protoc: No such file or directory
```

What can be the issue here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

protobuf is linked against [glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) library and alpine uses [musl](https://www.musl-libc.org/) (and older alpine used [uclibc](https://uclibc.org/about.html)). They are not compatible. The error you are seeing comes from the linker not finding the libc standard library `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`. You can check that, by issuing [ldd](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ldd.1.html) command:

```
$ ldd /bin/protoc 
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7faa1a641000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7faa1a641000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7faa1a641000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7faa1a641000)
Error loading shared library ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: No such file or directory (needed by /bin/protoc)
```

The file exists and the PATH is ok.
To fix this you may install glibc on alpine (not recommended) or just move to a normal linux container.

@edit: My old answer was not true, bash nor sh does not source `/etc/profile` by default, only when supplied with `-l` option.

Comment: `So your env variable will be overwritten.` Then why `echo $PATH` inside container shows correct $PATH?

Comment: Och, just tested that, and bash and sh does not source /etc/profile by default (only with `-l` option). So it's not that, it has to be musl, and protobuf probably needs libc.